# C#: XML how do I replace left angle brackets?

Tags: c#, xml, replace, brackets

The XML is provided as a string:

```
<Document>
    <Name>Intel ICU v5</Name>
    <Description>Intel ICU S<span id=\"ms-rterangecursor-end\">ite</Description>
<Document>
```

My program hates the fact the Description tag has an escape left angle bracket within the value. How do I replace this with "<" as left angle brackets are everywhere in the XML string.
I cannot store the XML values to a class object I've made if the values aren't readable.

EDIT: I forgot to add, I'm trying to deserialize the content to an object I've made.

EDIT2: Minimal reproducible example

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class XmlObject {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        XmlObject newObject = getNewXMLObject();
    }
    
    public static XmlObject getNewXMLObject() {
        string xmlString = "<Document><Name>Intel ICU v5</Name><Description>Intel ICU S<span id=\"ms-rterangecursor-end\">ite</Description><Document>";
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "Document";
        var xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlObject), xRoot);
        XmlObject xmlObj = new XmlObject();

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        using(TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString)) {
            xmlObj = (XmlObject) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return xmlObj;
    }
}
```

Any help, suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I forgot to add, I'm trying to deserialize the content to an object I've made" - please provide the code that does the deserialization. Basically, a [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: @JonSkeet Provided. Cheers

Comment: And are *all* the extra elements Span elements? (It's not that this is an escaped angle bracket - you've just got a Span element in the middle of your Description element.) Do they occur all through the document, or just in Description elements?

Comment: Actually, this isn't valid XML... the `<span>` element is never closed. It's not deserialization that's failing - it's `XDocument.Parse`. Where does this not-quite-XML come from?

Comment: I'm loading the XML strings from an old database to put into objects and then uploading the data from these objects to a new database. From the general look of the data, the descriptions seem to contain HTML similar to the span elements. I don't see anything like that in between other tags.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar to" the span elements? Basically you're going to have to be *really precise* about what needs removing, otherwise we won't be able to help you. For example, if they're always *exactly* `<span id="ms-rterangecursor-end">` then you can just use `string.Replace`. If they vary, you may find a regular expression will work - but we can't be any more precise than that in trying to help you unless you're more precise in what you're trying to remove.

Comment: @JonSkeet String.Replace seems to be working for this particular error well for the moment. I have around 1600 of these XML strings coming through though with different errors to why they can't be deserialized so I may be back later in the week if there's one that doesn't quite accept the string.replace. 
This is so far the best answer though. Thanks
EDIT: I spoke too soon. New-ish Error, same problem.       
"System.Xml.XmlException: The 'Description' start tag on line 1 position 163 does not match the end tag of 'span'. Line 1, position 220."

Comment: Okay, so you need to look at that span to see whether it's just got different content... and see whether there are any non-span tags in there.

Comment: @JonSkeet
It was long winded but I replaced all variations of the left angle bracket in all strings accompanied by: span, div, table, p, tbody, tr, td... etc. So far it's working well. Thanks for the solution
EDIT: I also replaced the following symbols: &, ', ", >

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with valid XML and just pasted it with a few errors, you can read the `Value` of an XElement and it will skip any embedded elements in the text.  EG  This

```
var xml = @"
<Document>
    <Name>Intel ICU v5</Name>
    <Description>Intel ICU S<span id=""ms-rterangecursor-end""/>ite</Description>
</Document>
";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var value = doc.Root.Element("Description").Value;

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

outputs

```
Intel ICU Site
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response.
I forgot to mention I'm trying to deserialize the XML string contents to an object.
Regardless, your code isn't working on my end.

Error> "'The 'span' start tag on line 1 position 235 does not match the end tag of 'Description'. Line 1, position 272.'"

Comment: The string you posted simply isn't XML as the `span` and `Document` elements are not closed.

Comment: The value between the description tags is a bit of HTML I'm guessing. It's data being retrieved from an old database... Unfortunately it wasn't stored in the best way

Comment: @zardoss: Is the problematic text *always* `<span id="ms-rterangecursor-end">`? Can you just use string replacements to remove it?

Comment: @zardoss - if this is html, then use an html parser. For example, HtmlAgilityPack. Load your xml/html to HTMLDocument and save it - you will get a correct document with closed tags at the output.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's not always specifically that - as I continue through the data, I get varied errors but the majority being div or spans with left angle brackets causing problems. Others refer to Parsing errors with entity name but that's out of scope for this. I was hoping to find something that interpreted the XML regardless of the values between the tags having left/right angle brackets.

I just attempted a string replacement with "&lt;" and "&gt;" but it doesn't quite have that universal impact on the data. Although I think this is on the right track. I will have to do some fiddling to see.